# Static ViewHolder Pattern. So whats the pattern for onClick inside this static Viewholder?

Tags: java, android, performance, design-patterns, android-recyclerview

I know.

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

static ViewHolder its recommended.

also onClick() in ViewHolder constructor its recommended instead of in onBind() method.

```
public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

but know we have inner onClick()  in static ViewHolder class

```
  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "position = " + getAdapterPosition());
        }
```

and now is my question after all this recommendations.

Whats now its recommended if for example I want to delete item from list in this recycler and notifi adapter.

My list must be static OK..
But still can't use notifyDataSetChanged() in inner onClick();

any recommendations for this? pattern? or usefull example would be great.
Or how You doing this in Your projects.

thx!

Answer (score 1):

> My list must be static OK

You don't need to make your dataset list static. It would go wrong in some cases if you do that.

> But still can't use notifyDataSetChanged() in inner onClick();

You don't need to or you shouldn't do that.

Let me explain you. The job of ViewHolder is holding the individual items in row layouts to avoid lookup for `findViewById()` for them each time[.See this video for more detailed explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA).

What you should do is to provide a callback or a listener to your adapter and transfer the ownership of data changes happening inside your adapter to your activity.

For example. Let's take a simple item click listener like this:

```
public interface ItemClickListener<T>{
  void onItemClick(int position, T item)
}
```

Now, inside your adapter, create a reference to that interface and provide setter like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ...{
  ...
  ...
  private ItemClickListener<MyItemModel> clickListener;

  public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener<MyItemModel> clickListener{
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
  } 

}
```

Now what you need to do inside ViewHolder is to dispatch the click event to your custom listener like this:
Your ViewHolder doesn't need to be static. Static inner classes are good because they don't keep reference to outer classes. The purpose of ViewHolder is to bind individual views and specify a tag of its instance to view to identify later while scrolling without doing `findViewById()`.

```
 public class ViewHolder extends ...{
        ...
        ...
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "position = " + getAdapterPosition());
            if(clickListener!=null){
                 clickListener.onItemClick(position , myList.get(position))
           }
        } 

}
```

So, you can access your item and position when user clicked, manipulate data and notify to adapter in your activity like below:

```
public class MyActivity extends  Activity implements ItemClickListener<MyItemModel>{

  ....
  ...
  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myList);
  myAdapter.setItemClickListener(this);

  ...
  ...

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(int position,MyItemModel item) 
    myAdapter.myList.manipulateDataOrWhaever();
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

If you want to keep your `ViewHolder` static to avoid implicit references to outer class. you can register click listener inside `onBindViewHolder()` like this:

```
....onBindViewHolder() {
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(){
    ....//same as click listener on ViewHolder

    }

}
```

Comment: If my ViewHolder is not static I'm doing the same like you. So yea for me its a good way. But I readed this should be static because avoiding impilicit reference for ViewHolder ( event on Google example https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html and more ). I need to test performance with static and non static ViewHolder. Anyway thx for Your explain!

Comment: but you can keep your viewholder static and its always a good practice. You can register listener inside onbindviewholder().

Comment: and making dataset list static will also cause a memory leak.